# Is there a way to force PHP on Windows to provide paths with forward slashes?

Tags: php, windows, path

I'm the only Windows developer in my office, and we have a lot of code that looks like this:

```
$fileName = preg_replace("/^(extend|base)\//", "", $fileName);
```

$fileName generally comes from **FILE** or something similar.

In order to get this code to work on my machine, I've had to start a whole bunch of functions with:

```
$fileName   = str_replace("\\", "/", $fileName);
```

Is there a better way to go about this, like a php.ini setting, or something I can define on my machine specifically, to force PHP to provide files and paths with forward slashes instead of backslashes?

EDIT: Using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is certainly one option, but it entails hours and hours of changing code all over the place.

To clarify, the question is not "how can I change my code", but "is there a setting to force a unix-like directory separator?"

Comment: You might have luck with running a Cygwin PHP binary instead. However that's a somewhat involving setup. Also consider `strtr` instead of `str_replace`.

Comment: Actually, that might just work.  I already have Cygwin running, maybe I can just execute PHP through Cygwin's bash.

Comment: Nah, you need the cygwin port of the php runtime. Otherwise it will directly call through to the win32 api.

Answer (score 2):

There is a DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant defined for you. Use it instead of "/" or "\".

Edit: (Also, I thought (can't check at the moment) that PHP on Windows allowed the use of forward slash just fine.)

Edit 2: Or just do this:

```
$fileName = preg_replace("/^(extend|base)[\/\\]/", "", $fileName);
```

Comment: This will also make your code more portable easier to transfer if you ever change your hosting. Additionally it means if some awesome OS comes along that decides to use some non-standard directory separator you're covered. Don't know why you would want to be but you are.

Comment: Windows allows the use of "/" or "\" if you want to try to access the files.  But if you're trying to compare against a path from the system, it doesn't help.  The path comes in with "\", so having a preg_match() string that has "/" in it returns false.